# Xcode sub navigation views

Tags: iphone, objective-c, button, navigation, xcode5

Does anyone know of any good tutorials for the following please?

Im new to Xcode and dont know where to start with this.

I have a ViewController that is the root View and has 6 navigation buttons (UIButton) on it. Depending on which button that is clicked, the user will see a sub-navigation View of that section with further button options on it.

So e.g top level will have buttons Where to Eat, What to Do...
Then clicking on Where to Eat will show Restaurants, Fast Food ....etc

I would like to do this programatically. I can do it using Storyboards and using multiple views, but it gets very messy as there are a lot of views on the screen eventually.

I have followed a tutorial [HERE](http://besthobby.org/index.php/component/relatedvideos/?vid=t9E5p1bME3c) on how it is done for TableViewControllers, but I need something similar for buttons.

Im not sure what this function is called - have been searching for sub-navigation for the last while but nothing matches what I need to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Check out UIViewController's method presentViewController:animated:completion: method. It is available in iOS 5.0 and up. Let's say you have one of the button's linked to run the buttonOneActivated: method:

```
-(IBAction)buttonOneActivated:(id)sender
{
    UISubViewController *subViewController = [[UISubViewController alloc] init];

    [self presentViewController:subViewController
                       animated:YES
                     completion:NULL];
}
```

And in UISubViewController's implementation, let's say you have another button in order to return to the parent:

```
-(IBAction)returnToParent:(id)sender
{
    [[self presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES
                                                        completion:NULL];
}
```